# Find Freelancer By Zip Code Look-up Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, google-geocoder, laravel-5.6

I have an application where I have roles setup through middleware as freelancer, employer, and admin. I would like to find freelancers by a given zip code and find employers by a given zip code, depending on which role is searching for which. Is there a package that can help do this with geocode... Something similar to task rabbit website for example. I have searched on google and refined my search and there is not much on the subject. I know Google has an API that can be used. What is the logic on this and how do I get started. Maybe a good tutorial... thanks

Comment: Have you considered downloading a zip to latitude/longitude database, and just writing the necessary queries?

Comment: I have considered that, but the upkeep on zip codes that change is a nightmare when scaling, I have heard, not to mention the the database being bloated.

Comment: There are services that provide you the data, with regular updates. It's certainly not a nightmare.

Comment: Would you know of a specific free service and the logic to implement?

Comment: I doubt you'll find a free service that guarantees updates. At the end of the day, you get what you pay for.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will wait for another answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could try using [geo code apis](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start?csw=1)

For example, to lookup zip 77379 use a request like this:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=77379&sensor=true

then from the response object take geometry.location

```
geometry: {
     bounds: {
        northeast: {
               lat: 30.088189,
               lng: -95.47364999999999
        },
       southwest: {
               lat: 29.9871611,
               lng: -95.5887879
       }
     },
     location: {
              lat: 30.0314279,
              lng: -95.5302337
     },
     location_type: "APPROXIMATE",
     viewport: {
       northeast: {
               lat: 30.088189,
               lng: -95.47364999999999
      },
      southwest: {
              lat: 29.9871611,
              lng: -95.5887879
     }
   }
 }
```

and from lat and lng do sql query to find users and filter them by role_id

hope this will help you.

Comment: This is a good option, but beware there are [usage limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage-limits), and also you're only allowed to cache the data per Google's terms of service (so not indefinitely).

Comment: @siddhant sankhe Thanks for that example. I will take a look at it and study the json...